# SQL code copy / pasted from Excel document,with no visible errors, will not execute

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, character-encoding

I am using the code from this website (up until the end of the first case statement)-

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/abbreviation/

```
DECLARE @StateCode char(2)
SET @StateCode = 'TX'
SELECT 'State name from state code' =
CASE 
WHEN @StateCode = 'AK' THEN 'ALASKA'
WHEN @StateCode = 'AL' THEN 'ALABAMA'...
...WHEN @StateCode = 'WV' THEN 'WEST VIRGINIA'
WHEN @StateCode = 'WY' THEN 'WYOMING'
ELSE '' END
GO
```

This code runs fine if I copy / paste from the website directly into SSMS.

If I copy / paste this code (from the website) into Excel, and then copy / paste from Excel to SSMS, the code will not run anymore even though it is visibly the same as the original code.  SSMS is bringing up syntax errors all throughout the code.

The problem seems to be with the space (" ") characters; If replace all of the "space characters" with "real" spaces, the errors will go away and the code will run correctly.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What happens if you copy/paste it into a text editor instead of Excel?

Comment: It could be that web code includes not real spaces (code=32), but non-breaking spaces (code=160) - and SSMS and Excel deal with it differently. Or there can be some other HTML problem - Excel knows HTML, SSMS not. You can also try to paste into excel as unformatted text (if such option exists in Paste Special).

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer No issues if I use notepad.  Only with Excel..

Comment: I don't have documentation, but I saw someone on here once say that Excel is notorious for adding funky white space characters around single-quotes.

Comment: Excel does very strange things, indeed.  If it's only happening in Excel, just don't use Excel for copy/paste. :)

Comment: This might be due to different apps preserving formatting differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being that the spaces (ascii 32) were being replaced by non-breaking spaces (ascii 160).  Once the non-breaking spaces were replaced the code ran correctly.

Here are also a few links you can use to test this, which will tell you which ascii value a character is

http://asciivalue.com/

http://slayeroffice.com/tools/ascii/

Answer (score 0):

There is a little issue with the `SELECT` statement. You can rewrite as

```
SELECT 'State name from state code' + ' =' +
CASE 
WHEN @StateCode = 'AK' THEN 'ALASKA'
WHEN @StateCode = 'AL' THEN 'ALABAMA'
WHEN @StateCode = 'WV' THEN 'WEST VIRGINIA'
WHEN @StateCode = 'WY' THEN 'WYOMING'
ELSE NULL END AS Mycolumn
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying from excel can introduce a non-breaking space into text.  Take one of those "spaces" that are showing as errors and do a find replace with a regular space.

Answer (score 0):

When pasting from Excel I always use Notepad (actually I use NotePad++) in between.  Excel always seems to add junk.  Paste your code into Notepad and see if there are any funky characters or odd spacing.  Then remove it and paste your code form there.

Answer (score 0):

When storing something in Excel the best practice for copying is to select cell with text you need to copy and copy it from the Formula Bar, not from cell directly. While storing data in the cells Excel adds a few invisible characters: Line breaks etc.